# PHP won't display "0" value string?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, custom-post-type

I'm using Wordpress with Genesis Framework, and I'm having trouble getting values of custom fields to display if they're "0". The values come from a form, and the 0 values are indeed in the post meta in my database. If I change them to anything else, they display perfectly on the single-posttype.php template. However, if they are set to 0, then nothing is displayed. I've included an example of the code I'm using, and yes, I'm aware of my dirty short codes, but it's ok. I know my place. Help?

```
 $customField = genesis_get_custom_field('customField');

   add_action('hookLocation','myDirtyShortcodes');
   function myDirtyShortcodes(){

      echo do_shortcode('[some dirtyshortcodehere'.$customField.' more dirty shortcode]'); 
    }
```

Comment: Is `$customField` a global?

Comment: Nope. It's declared only in that template file.

Answer (score 0):

So as @Machevity mentioned try this way:

```
   add_action('hookLocation','myDirtyShortcodes');
   function myDirtyShortcodes(){
      $customField = genesis_get_custom_field('customField');
      echo do_shortcode('[some dirtyshortcodehere'.$customField.' more dirty shortcode]'); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. the genesis_get_custom_field function used a poor method of checking the variable for a null value.

Inside of genesis_get_custom_field,

```
if ( ! $custom_field )
return '';
```

Was replaced with

```
if($custom_field === '')
    return '';
```

In the original function, "0" was returning false. But this quick change (thanks to /u/gu3st12 on Reddit).